# Issue with showing more results

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I'm working on a website to try and learn coding and am making a simple search site.

When the user searches for either "Restaurant" or "Restaurants" (or some other words but I'm just using these as examples), a list of words that could help refine the search such as "American Food" or "Chinese Food" appears. But there is quite a few refining words to choose from so I stored all of them in a database, and am using Javascript to display more ( when you first go there is a limit of 10 refining words on the page but when you click **see more** the rest appear.) Anyways, I thought that I would do a mysql select to show rows 1-10 and then another mysql select for rows 11 to the end of all the rows in the div that is not displayed until the user clicks **see more**. But I keep getting this error

> Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /Users/searchswitch.php on line 17
>
> Warning: mysql_close(): 4 is not a valid MySQL-Link resource in /Users/searchswitch.php on line 22

What is causing this? Also, I know (even being a new programmer) that my code is not very clean, how can I clean this up)

Here's the code: I left out the other switch cases to make it easier to read but if you need any more info, I'll be glad to help! Thanks for all help!

```
switch ($q) {
            case "Restaurants" || "Restaurant":
                echo "<hr /><span><strong>Refine Search</strong><br/><br/>";
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE catnumber='1' LIMIT 0,10");

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo "<a href='search.php?q=". $row['subcat'] ."'/>" . $row['subcat'] ."</a>";
                    echo "<br />";
                }
                mysql_close($link);

                echo "<a href='#' id='example-show' class='showLink' onclick='showHide(\"example\");return false;'><br/>See more</a></span><div id='example' style='display:none;'>";
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE catnumber='1' LIMIT 11,100");

                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                    echo "<a href='search.php?q=". $row['subcat'] ."'/>" . $row['subcat'] ."</a>";
                    echo "<br />";
                }
                mysql_close($link);

                echo"<br/><a href='#' id='example-hide' class='hideLink' onclick='showHide(\"example\");return false;'>Hide</a></div>";

            break;
```

Oh also want to point out that line 17 is *while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))* and line 22 is *mysql_close($link);*

Comment: $link is the variable i assigned my mysql connect to...like $link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '********');

Comment: what your $result is echoing use -- $result = mysql_query($myQuery) or die($myQuery."<br/><br/>".mysql_error());
and tell me then

Comment: remove the mysql_close and try it. You are closing a connection and there is nothing to run your query against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this your query will work fine

```
switch ($q) {
        case "Restaurants" || "Restaurant":
            echo "<hr /><span><strong>Refine Search</strong><br/><br/>";
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE catnumber='1' LIMIT 0,10");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<a href='search.php?q=". $row['subcat'] ."'/>" . $row['subcat'] ."</a>";
                echo "<br />";
            }


            echo "<a href='#' id='example-show' class='showLink' onclick='showHide(\"example\");return false;'><br/>See more</a></span><div id='example' style='display:none;'>";
            $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM subcat WHERE catnumber='1' LIMIT 11,100");

            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
            {
                echo "<a href='search.php?q=". $row['subcat'] ."'/>" . $row['subcat'] ."</a>";
                echo "<br />";
            }


            echo"<br/><a href='#' id='example-hide' class='hideLink' onclick='showHide(\"example\");return false;'>Hide</a></div>";

        break;
```